# How to change room db expected column order? Pre-packaged database has an invalid schema error

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

I need to prepopulate db. I have two problems, one is: roomdb not exporting schema, even though exportSchema is set to true. second is: room db reordering columns and giving me error of `Pre-packaged database has an invalid schema`. Now the first problem can be omitted, but second problem must be resolved to move forward. I have no idea why this is happening. I have created database in sqlite browser and saw the same issue.
The error is:

```
Expected:
TableInfo{name='words', columns={en=Column{name='en', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='undefined'}, pl=Column{name='pl', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, speech=Column{name='speech', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
 Found:
TableInfo{name='words', columns={id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='undefined'}, en=Column{name='en', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, pl=Column{name='pl', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, speech=Column{name='speech', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
```

as seen above the 'en' column and 'id' column in different position. Not sure but I suspect this is the reason of the error.

table creation statement:

```
CREATE TABLE words (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, en TEXT, pl TEXT, speech TEXT)
```

Entity:

```
@Entity(tableName = "words")
data class MyEntity (
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")val id: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "en") val englishWord: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "pl") val polishWord: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "speech") val speech: String?
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to change room db expected column order?

The order of the columns, between **expected** *(the schema that Room expects according to the `@Entity` annotated classes that have been specified in the `entities` parameter of the respective `@Database` annotated class(es))* and the **found** *(the pre-populated database)* is **irrelevant**.

What matters is that the column definitions in the **found** table(s) match the **expected** definitions.

In other words, *after having a quick look at the expected v found*, you will see that the **id** column is expected to have a *NOT NULL* constraint, the table creation statement, as per the pre-populated database* does not include the **NOT NULL** constraint. i.e.

```
expected is ===> id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='undefined'}

found is ==> id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='undefined'}
```

To overcome this issue then you could have:-

```
`CREATE TABLE words (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, en TEXT, pl TEXT, speech TEXT)`
```

Comparing and trying to ascertain how to interpret the expected/found discrepancies is not the easiest task. It is easier to always ensure that what Room expects is used for the schema of the pre-populated database. This is as simple as:-

1. Creating the `@Entity` annotated class(es) and including them in the `entities` parameter of the `@Database` class(es).
2. Successfully compiling the project.
3. Using the Android Studio's **Android View** locating the class that is the same name as the `@Database` annotated class, but suffixed with **_Impl** in the **java(generated)** directories *(there will typically be at least two sub directories)*
4. Locating the **createAllTables** method, in which the **expected** SQL for creating the tables (as Room would use if it was left to create them).

   4.1 Note that the room_master_table need not be created as Room will create and maintain this as required.

You may need to convert the existing data which can be done easily in an SQLite tool by:-

1. Renaming the original table
2. Creating the table as per the Room SQL from the generated java (this has the original name)
3. Using SQL to copy the data from the renamed original

   3.1 This in the simplest scenario could be as simple as `INSERT INTO the_table SELECT * FROM the_renamed_original_table;`
4. Dropping the renamed original table

**Alternative Approach**

In your case an alternative could be to use `@ColumnInfo(name = "id")val id: Int?,`. However, you may wish to refer to [Why does @PrimaryKey val id: Int? = null works when creating a Room entity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76008121/why-does-primarykey-val-id-int-null-works-when-creating-a-room-entity/76011195#76011195) as using a nullable id is treated differently by room when inserting *(i.e. 0 is considered to be the value 0 rather than a generated value and thus if used could result in the row not being inserted or failing if another row exists with the value 0)*

- note that in some cases you cannot tailor the `@Entity` to suit a pre-populated/existing schema.

**Example of Generated Java for the Alternative Approach**

Consider your and the suggested nullable id as per:-

```
@Entity(tableName = "words")
data class MyEntity (
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")val id: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "en") val englishWord: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "pl") val polishWord: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "speech") val speech: String?
)

@Entity(tableName = "wordsV2")
data class MyEntityV2 (
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")val id: Int?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "en") val englishWord: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "pl") val polishWord: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "speech") val speech: String?
)
```

And for the sake of demonstrating the following:-

```
@Database(entities = [AutoGenTrueTable::class,AutoGenFalseTable::class,AutoGenFalseNullableTable::class,MyEntity::class,MyEntityV2::class], exportSchema = false, version = 1)
abstract class TheDatabase: RoomDatabase() { ....
```

- ignore all but **MyEntity** and **MyEntityV2** (used an existing project for the demostration)

Then finding the generated java:-

[image]

- as can be seen the words table has the NOT NULL constraint, the wordsv2 does not, so may suit.

  - see link above re difference of how Room handles inserts *(generation of the value for the id column)*.